# Return lists from a list of lists when given an input value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been hammering my head for some time over this issue but can't seem find a solution for this, hence I ask for the assistance. PS: still a bit new to programming

I have lists in a list:

```
[(2012, 'january', 'monday'), (2012, 'february', 'monday'), (2012, 'january', 'tuesday')]
```

What I want is a new list with lists, when giving in the input "monday':

```
[(2012, 'january', 'monday'), (2012, 'february', 'monday')]
```

So far my code:

```
lists = [(2012, 'january', 'monday'), (2012, 'february', 'monday'), (2012, 'january', 'tuesday')]

day = input("Give day: ") #monday

def select_monday(lists, day):
    list2 = []
    for list in lists:
        if list[2] == day: #from here I'm stuck and do not know how to continue
            list2.append(list[2])
        else:
            return None
    return list2
```

Result: `None`

I have no clue how to get all the lists with a certain value

Comment: To clarify, you have a list of tuples, and it appears that you want a dictionary with 'monday' and 'tuesday' as (unique) keys? And a list of tuples as values for the dictionary?

Comment: Have you tried using a `defaultdict`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code was fine, except, you don't need `else` statement, because otherwise during next iteration you will loose the results from the previous steps; also you should actually call your function:

```
lists = [(2012, 'january', 'monday'), (2012, 'february', 'monday'), (2012, 'january', 'tuesday')]

day = input("Give day: ") #monday

def select_monday(lists, day):
    list2 = []
    for list in lists:
        if list[2] == day: #from here I'm stuck and do not know how to continue
            list2.append(list)
    return list2

print(select_monday(lists, day))
```

And here's a more compact function:

```
def select_monday_2(lists, day):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x[2] == day, lists))

print(select_monday_2(lists, day))
```

Comment: Thank you. It was indeed the else statement that screwed me over

Answer (score 0):

You return `None` if the day is not Monday.
This works better:

```
def select_monday(lists, day):
    list2 = []
    for lst in lists:
        if lst[2] == day:
            list2.append(lst)
    return list2
```

Furthermore, append the whole list, not only the weekday.
Finally, better not use `list` as variable name because it is a built-in.

Now:

```
>>> select_monday(lists, day)
[(2012, 'january', 'monday'), (2012, 'february', 'monday')]
```

Shorter alternative, using a list comprehension:

```
>>> [x for x in lists if x[2] == day]
[(2012, 'january', 'monday'), (2012, 'february', 'monday')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is the else statement. If even one of the checks is false then it will `return None`. Remove the else statement and get rid of the `[2]` on the list in the `append` statement, unless you just want to append the day.

```
lists = [(2012, 'january', 'monday'), (2012, 'february', 'monday'), (2012, 'january', 'tuesday')]

day = input("Give day: ") #monday

def select_monday(lists, day):
    list2 = []
    for list in lists:
        if list[2] == day: #from here I'm stuck and do not know how to continue
            list2.append(list)
    return list2
```